# How to output Database Results in given format using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, string-formatting

I was trying to print out the table data in a particular format like the one I have attached below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s \n", "STUDENT ID", "EMAIL ID", "NAME", "AGE", "GRADE");
```

Increase the `x` in `%xs`to increase the spaces.
Apply loop for the hyphens (`-`)
and loop over your result from db in a similar way to the snippet above.